# how to split a text tile of names into 4 separate array indexes in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, split, format

I am formatting text in a file and need to have each word in the file as a separate array index.  here is an example of the text in the file:

Sanders, Bernie     M    Democrat

Boehner, John       M    Republican

Pelosi, Nancy       F    Democrat

Rubio, Mario        M    Republican

here is what I have tried, to separate the text.

```
         char[] whitespace = new char[] { ' ', '\t'};
         string[] separate = line.Split(whitespace);
```

There are several spaces before and after the "m" or "f", which makes it hard to separate, since they are regular spaces and not created with a tab.  so it adds sever blank spaces to my array. Once I format the text with:

```
         string formatted = string.Format("{2} {1} {0}", separate);
         formatted = formatted.Replace(",", "");
         Console.WriteLine("Dear " + formatted + ":");
```

the result needs to be:

Dear Mr. Bernie Sanders: ..etc

Comment: Are you getting the empty string or white space in your split array?  If you get the empty string, you can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` as a second parameter to ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example. You will have to keep track of all the indexes.

Reference to regular expression chars and meanings.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Regex is really powerful once you get the hang of it.

Here I am using `\s+` The `\s` is any whitespace character. The `+` makes it 'greedy'. Means match any whitespace character 1 or More times. You can use the `*` quantifier which means 0 or More times. Be careful with that one xD

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //extra spaces everywhere
            string person = "Sanders, Bernie     M       Democrat\nBoehner,  John    M  Republican";
            var stripchars = new Regex(@"\s+");
            person = stripchars.Replace(person, " ");
            string[] line = person.Split('\n'); // spit on each new line
            // temp vars to hold key pieces of information
            string firstname = "";
            string lastname = "";
            string sex = "";
            string party = "";
            string formatted = "";

            // the new line string
            for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++ )
            {

                string[] tempCells = line[i].Split(' ');
                //each cell in the line
                for (int k = 0; k < tempCells.Length; k++)
                {
                    firstname = tempCells[0].Replace(",", "");
                    lastname = tempCells[1];
                    sex = tempCells[2];
                    party = tempCells[3];
                }
                //updated to use tunrary
                string malefemale = sex == "M" ? "Mr." : "Ms.";
                formatted = "Dear " + malefemale + " " + lastname + " " + firstname + ":";

                Console.WriteLine(formatted);
            }
            Console.Read();//pause
        }
    }

}
```

Output: `Dear John Boehner:`

Comment: He has M and F, those aren't initials, they're gender.

Comment: I think this does not really solve the problem at hand. If there are several whitespaces before and after the gender, this will not work. Also the second loop is not needed.

Comment: @timcbaoth I updated code with extra whitespaces. I didn't read far enough before i started coding at first...typical of me xD

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;) That looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

My best bet would be to use a regular expression.

```
var str = "Sanders,\tBernie    M   Democrat";
var whitespaces = new Regex(@"\s+");
str = whitespaces.Replace(str, " ");
var ar = str.Split(' ');
```

\s+ stands for 1 or more whitespaces, which will be replaced with just one whitespace, so you can easily split.

Answer (score 1):

Another regular expression:

```
string[] wordArray = Regex.Split("This is \t my string of words!,", "[^a-zA-Z]+");
```